# Place an Add button to an android picker with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, ios, button, uiactionsheet, picker

I would like to display a Android Spinner which shows data from a SQLite DB.

The user however should be able to add new items to this Spinner.

On the iPhone / iOS I use ActionSheetPicker to achive this goal. It looks like this: [image: iPhone ActionSheetPicker with Add button]

How to to this with Android?

Comment: Are you talking about [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)?

Comment: Yes in Android it's called Spinner

Comment: And there is an example of how to use it and populate it - do you expect ready solution?

Comment: For example this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/)

Comment: Is this the only solution??

Comment: I do not want to insert the new labels in the database - only if the user clicks save later

Comment: And everything in one popup would be nice - in the activity are other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it works with a CursorAdapter but 
**the following code does about the same as the UIPicker** on iOS:

The code does the following:

1. Create / get the data for the Spinner
2. Use Buttons instead of Spinners on the activity
3. Create an AlertDialog (pop-up) which displays the Spinner and an add-button
4. The add-button creates another popup with a EditText (text-field)

   ```
   ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
   items.add("One");
   items.add("Two");
   items.add("Three");
   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

   final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCountry);
   selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") View v) {
           new AlertDialog.Builder(main)
           .setTitle("Please choose a country")
           .setPositiveButton("Add Country", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   final EditText view = new EditText(main);
                   new AlertDialog.Builder(main)
                       .setTitle("Please enter a name")
                       .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               adapter.add(view.getText().toString());
                               selectBtn.setText(view.getText().toString());
                           }
                       })
                       .setNegativeButton("cancel", null)
                       .setView(view)
                       .show();
               }
           })
           .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   selectBtn.setText(adapter.getItem(which));
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           }).create().show();
       }
   });
   ```

Here are the resulting pictures:

Activity:
[image: Activity]

AlertDialog with Spinner and Button:
[image: AlertDialog with Spinner and Button]

AlertDialog with text input:
[image: AlertDialog with text input]